# PHP / Wordpress: Change UTC (?) dates in titles to "human" dates

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date

PHP / Wordpress: Change UTC (?) dates in titles to "human" dates

I have about 10,000 Wordpress records.

About 10% of them have dates in their titles embedded as strings in a format that I'm unfamiliar with (I THINK it's UTC?). I need them all in human readable format of "l, F js, Y"

For example

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog on 2015-01-01T00:00:00

to

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog on Thursday, January 1st, 2015

(Note: I am assuming that the "T00:00:00" portion is the time. I dont need that.

What I DO know: I know that I can create a variable to change the date format like this

```
$correctedDate = date($wordpressDateInTheTitle, "l, F js, Y")
```

What I do NOT know is how to extract & replace the UTC date from each title with $correctedDate

So perhaps something like

```
$wordpressTitle = get_the_title();
$badDate = <<extract the date from $wordpressTitle>>;
$correctedDate = date($badDate, "l, F js, Y");
$newTitle = "'.$wordpressTitle <<but replace the $badDate with $correctedDate>>.'"
$sql = "UPDATE wp_post SET 'title' = REPLACE ($wordpressTitle,$newTitle);"
```

If it helps, the dates are ALWAYS the last part of the string (nothing is after the date EVER) so perhaps a concatination from the right to the left?

Or perhaps a find and replace (does php have such a thing) in which any string that starts with 2015 or 2016 is replaced it $correctedDate?

A little hand holding here to get me over the hump...?

Comment: So all your dates are in this format `2015-01-01T00:00:00`?

Comment: It looks like all of your dates are going to have the exact same character length. You could just use `substr` to extract the date, `strtotime` to convert it and finally `str_replace`.

Comment: Try using `preg_replace_callback` with a pattern like `/(201[\d]-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2})(.+){9}$/`. In the callback, use `date` and `strtotime` to format the date.

Comment: @tuananh yes, all dates are in that format

Answer (score 2):

Just like RonaldPK said, this would probably work for you:

```
$title = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog on 2015-01-01T00:00:00";
$title = preg_replace_callback('/\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}$/', function($matches){
  return date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($matches[0]));
}, $title);
echo $title;
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for this problem, if your dates are strictly in this format and are always the last part of string, you can extract it by finding the last occurrence of `space` using `strrpos` and cut it till the end:

```
$badDate = substr($wordpressTitle, strrpos($wordpressTitle, ' ')+1);
```

Then do whatever you want with $badDate using `date` and `strtotime`.

Generally, even your dates not always the last part of string, you still can use regular expression to search for them, like what RonaldPK suggested.